# Issue updating the state in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-state

In my Login component, I am trying to validate the user input and set the errors using React state, but I am facing issue updating the `errorState`.

Here's my Login component

```js
const Login = () => {
    const [state, setState] = React.useState({email: '', password: ''});

    const initialErrorState = {emailError: '', passwordError: ''};
    const [errorState, setErrorState] = React.useState(initialErrorState);

    const handleChange = (e, {name, value}) => {
        setState({...state, [name]: value});
    }

    const validate = () => {
        const emailRegEx = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

        state.email === '' ? setErrorState({...errorState, emailError: "Email is required"}) :
            !state.email.match(emailRegEx) ? setErrorState({...errorState, emailError: "Email is invalid"}) :
            setErrorState({...errorState, emailError: ''});

        state.password === '' ? setErrorState({...errorState, passwordError: 'Password is required'}) :
        setErrorState({...errorState, passwordError: ''});
    }

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        validate();
        console.log(errorState);

        if (!(JSON.stringify(errorState) === JSON.stringify(initialErrorState)))
            return;

        //  console.log(state);
    }

    return (
        <Container>
            <h1>Login</h1>
            <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <Form.Input 
                    label="Email"
                    placeholder="example@gmail.com"
                    name="email"
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    error={errorState.emailError ? errorState.emailError : null}
                />
                <Form.Input 
                    label="Password"
                    type="password"
                    name="password"
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    error={errorState.passwordError ? errorState.passwordError : null}
                />
                <Form.Button 
                    type="submit"
                    content="Login"
                />
            </Form>
        </Container>
    );
};
```

Calling `validate()` function do not set the `emailError` in my `errorState`. It only sets `passwordError`. Console logging `errorState` after calling `validate()` function gives following.
*Deliberately keeping email and password fields empty and pressing login button multiple times*

```
{emailError: '', passwordError: ''}
Login.js:29 {emailError: '', passwordError: 'Password is required'}
Login.js:29 {emailError: '', passwordError: 'Password is required'}
Login.js:29 {emailError: '', passwordError: 'Password is required'}
Login.js:29 {emailError: '', passwordError: 'Password is required'}
```

If I modify the validate function to following 
*Placing password validation above the email validation*

```js
const validate = () => {
        const emailRegEx = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

        state.password === '' ? setErrorState({...errorState, passwordError: 'Password is required'}) :
        setErrorState({...errorState, passwordError: ''});

        state.email === '' ? setErrorState({...errorState, emailError: "Email is required"}) :
            !state.email.match(emailRegEx) ? setErrorState({...errorState, emailError: "Email is invalid"}) :
            setErrorState({...errorState, emailError: ''});
    }
```

This time my `emailError` is set but `passwordError` is not set. Console logging `errorState` after calling `validate()` function gives following.
*Again deliberately keeping email and password fields empty and pressing login button multiple times*

```
{emailError: '', passwordError: ''}
Login.js:29 {emailError: 'Email is required', passwordError: ''}
Login.js:29 {emailError: 'Email is required', passwordError: ''}
Login.js:29 {emailError: 'Email is required', passwordError: ''}
```

Can anyone help me understanding why this is happening? why both properties of my `errorState` object are not setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React `setState` calls are batched and enqueued, State updates [may be async](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous). If you try to access the state immediately after setting it, you won't get the correct value.

> React may batch multiple setState() calls into a single update for performance.
>
> Because this.props and this.state may be updated asynchronously, you
> should not rely on their values for calculating the next state.

You can use the [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook to listen to state changes, this will trigger everytime when its dependencies changes

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(errorState)
},[errorState])
```

Comment: Even better would be to just derive `errorState` from the other form state using `React.useMemo`.